# Word automation services fails opening file with error code 0x80040266

Tags: 2010, pdf, word-automation

I'm using word automation services to convert a docx file in a pdf. In my development machine it works great, but moving to a staging enviroment it crashes while opening the file. In the logs I find this error message, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
Word failed to open the document (Error Code = 0x80040266)
```

Any idea? Here's the log...

```
07/23/2012 23:00:14.65  w3wp.exe (0x12A4)                           0x1C38  Word Automation Services        Office Viewing Architecture     wysp    Medium      AppWorker:e1bce35f-09e2-4ed5-bae5-fb2d991b804f response CantOpenDocument sent for request cdd30028-fcc0-494f-9f89-2e8a4df53668. Worker name WordAutomationServices, Document 00000001-0001-102c-8011-a3172f068592   00000001-0001-102c-8011-a3172f068592
07/23/2012 23:00:14.66  w3wp.exe (0x12A4)                           0x1C38  Word Automation Services        Service                         g281    Medium      Local Controller 'e0f6901d-a0ce-471a-8566-dcf80b12e662': Failure: <http://applicationsvil.benettongroup.org/sites/Twister/Created Docs/Riepilogo-a2906116-2496-43dd-84e1-f8ba6522c0cf.docx> not uploaded to <http://applicationsvil.benettongroup.org/sites/Twister/Converted Docs/Riepilogo-a2906116-2496-43dd-84e1-f8ba6522c0cf.pdf> (131174) 00000001-0001-102c-8011-a3172f068592
07/23/2012 23:00:14.81  w3wp.exe (0x12A4)                           0x0BC8  Word Automation Services        Word Web App File Open          b0v1    Medium      Word failed to open the document (Error Code = 0x80040266). 00000001-0001-102c-8011-a3172f068592
07/23/2012 23:00:14.81  w3wp.exe (0x12A4)                           0x0BC8  Word Automation Services        Office Performance Tracing      b0v2    Medium      end opening file 3gmkyjtz.thf.docx  00000001-0001-102c-8011-a3172f068592
07/23/2012 23:00:14.81  w3wp.exe (0x12A4)                           0x1C38  Word Automation Services        Office Viewing Architecture     b4em    Monitorable AppWorker:e1bce35f-09e2-4ed5-bae5-fb2d991b804f recycle worker process because the conversion failed with result CantOpenDocument. Worker is WordAutomationServices  00000001-0001-102c-8011-a3172f068592
```

Comment: Have you configured permissions for the word automation service account correctly ?

Comment: @MossFarmer I've never changed the permissions on this service. How do I do it and what permissions should it have?